# Weird javascript regexp replace issue

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following text

```
text(-) 3
```

Which I want to change into:

```
-3
```

So I wrote the following regular expression:

```
'text(-) 3'.replace(/text\((?:[^\)]+)\)/g, RegExp.$1);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/brcdv160/) - which doesn't work.

However, when I do the following

```
var output = 'text(-) 3'.replace(/text\(([^\)]+)\)/g, RegExp.$1);
output = 'text(-) 3'.replace(/text\((?:[^\)]+)\)/g, RegExp.$1);
```

(So in the first I've removed the `?:`) it works

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/brcdv160/1/)

So there must be something I've missed with grouping matches with regular expressions (or just something stupid). Any help would be appreciated!?

Comment: Maybe better use 'text(-) 3'.replace(/[^-\d]/g, ''); ?

Comment: I can't, because in my case other text can be present in the string which I don't want to replace and I really would like to know whats going on here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Code explanation

Removing `?:` makes the group *capturing*, which means that it will capture anything matched by `[^\)]+`, and the matched text is made available for replacement and backreference.

```
var output = 'text(-) 3'.replace(/text\(([^\)]+)\)/g, RegExp.$1);
```

When `String.replace` is called, `RegExp.$1` is not yet initialized, so the result in output will be `" 3"`. Then the regex is executed, and the capturing group captures `-` in `text(-)` and place it in capturing group 1.

The **deprecated** attribute `RegExp.$1` is also updated with the content of the capturing group 1 of the last `RegExp` execution.

Then on the next line:

```
output = 'text(-) 3'.replace(/text\((?:[^\)]+)\)/g, RegExp.$1);
```

Since `RegExp.$1` now contains `"-"`, the replacement give the result `"- 3"`.

`RegExp.$1` is **deprecated**, since it is shared between all execution of `RegExp` and extremely error prone. So are a bunch of other properties `RegExp.$2` to `RegExp.$9` which contains the content of the capturing group 2 to 9 of the latest execution.

### Solution

For your purpose, you should do this:

```
var output = 'text(-) 3'.replace(/text\(([^\)]+)\) */g, "$1");
```

It is not clear how many spaces after `)`, so I added  `*`. To refer to the content of a capturing group in the replacement, use `$1` in the replacement string.

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for

```
var output = 'text(-) 3'.replace(/text\(([^\)]+)\)/g, '$1');
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/brcdv160/4/)

**Problems with `'text(-) 3'.replace(/text\((?:[^\)]+)\)/g, RegExp.$1);`**

- `(?:[^\)]+)` is a non capturing group so the value is not captured in `$1`
- `RegExp.$1` Contains the capture group from the previous regex match and not the current

  That is

  ```
  var output = 'text(-) 3'.replace(/text\(([^\)]+)\)/g, RegExp.$1);
  output = 'text(-) 3'.replace(/text\((?:[^\)]+)\)/g, RegExp.$1);
  ```

  Here in the second statement the regex `RegExp.$1` is from the first statement and not from the second. So when used alone it is unset and does not create the expected output.